# How to print selected numbers from a list in python?

Tags: python

I want to print all atoms except H (hydrogen) from the pdb file. Here is the file

https://github.com/mahesh27dx/molecular_phys.git

Following code prints the objects of the file

```py
import numpy as np
import mdtraj as md

coord = md.load('alanine-dipeptide-nowater.pdb')
atoms, bonds = coord.topology.to_dataframe()
atoms
```

The result looks like this
[image]

From this table I want to print all the elements except H . I think it can be done in python using the list slicing. Could someone have any idea how it can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a pandas dataframe, not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should clarify that you want help with `mdtraj` or `pandas` specifically.

Anyway, it's as simple as `atoms.loc[atoms.element != 'H']`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also explain what 'loc' stands for?

Comment: In `pandas` (which is the package that introduced `DataFrame`) the `loc` function is one of the most important features. It allows selecting rows and columns either by name (index name) or by a `Series` of Boolean values. Here in this example we used an implicit Boolean series.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
print(*list(df[df.element!='H']['element']))
```

If you want the unique elements, you can do this:

```
print(*set(df[df.element!='H']['element']))
```